# Accessing star ratings from reviews, for multiple businesses

Tags: google-api, google-places, review

Is it possible to fetch the Google star rating for any business using the Google Places API?

I have a comparison website and want to display the Google star ratings for each business on my site.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The responses from the [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) and [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) APIs include a `rating` field.

However, two important warnings:

1. These APIs are both billed, and are quite expensive ($17 and $32 per 1000 requests, respectively). Making a Place Details request for each business displayed in a comparison will probably be economically infeasible.
2. The [Places API policies](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies) place a number of requirements on your use of Google's data. In particular, you cannot cache most data returned by the API (including ratings), and you cannot use the data alongside a non-Google map.